# Scanner input validation Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
while(!isValid){
    System.out.println("Enter house number: ");
    if(input.hasNextInt()){
        houseNum=input.nextInt();
        isValid=true;
    }
    else{
        System.err.print("Wrong input. Try again");
        isValid=false;
    }
}
```

There is my code. I want to make sure it doesnt throw an exception and also keeps asking user to enter correct input format which is an integer. But it keeps entering a infinite loop.

Comment: Remove the boolean flag. Use `while(input.hasNextInt()` and then `input.nextInt()`

Comment: `hasNextInt()` is exactly doing that ... making sure that the user already entered a valid whole number. No need to put your own validation around that.

Comment: @TheLostMind and GhostCat I get your point. However I want it to ask the user to input again if it recieves a wrong input.

Answer (score 0):

Add `input.nextLine();` to your `else` block.

That'll allow you get next value into the buffer rather than fall into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct solution is:

```
    while (!isValid) {
        System.out.println("Enter house number: ");
        if (input.hasNextInt()) {
            houseNum = input.nextInt();
            isValid = true;
        }
        else {
            System.err.print("Wrong input. Try again");
            isValid = false; // not really necessary; isValid was already false
        }
        input.nextLine();
    }
```

I skip a line from the input no matter if reading the number was successful or not. In case no number was read, this skips the entire incorrect line; in case a number was read, it just skips the newline after the number.